# Find rate of change of angle of slant from vertex of cone when a particle is moving on a circular periphery with an angular velocity of $\omega$.

Tags: differential-geometry, physics, 3d, solid-geometry, solid-angle

**Question :** Find the rate of change of the angle of slant from the vertex of the cone when a particle is moving on a circular periphery (base of the cone) with an angular velocity of $\omega$.

**My Attempt**

[image]

I guess the slant won't be changing in one plane. It's a case of $3D$ motion of the slant. How to solve?

Comment: Do you know how to: 1. Describe the position of the particle as a function of time and angular velocity; 2. Calculate the displacement from the vertex to the particle; 3. Calculate the angle between two vectors using the dot product?